# I have a website and when I put one page in the root it works fine but within a folder I get an error?

Tags: php, linux, debian, gnu

I have uploaded the same file on to the website. The php code in it looks like this 

`$f = fopen("http://thefreetechhelp.com/testsrc/top.txt", "r");
while(!feof($f)) { 
    echo fgets($f);
}
fclose($f);

?>  </code>`

And there is two of these in the document. Below are the links, notice how in the second one you get the error

http://thefreetechhelp.com/index.html

http://thefreetechhelp.com/articles/index.html

the server is Debian GNU/Linux if that helps

Comment: So, index.html contains the PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

The file you're copying contains references to other files with relative URLs. For instance, it contains:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="srcfiles/main.js"></script>
```

When you move the `index.html` to a folder, it expects to find the `srcfiles` folder in that folder as well. You need to replicate all the files that are accessed via relative paths in the folder, or change the references to use absolute paths.

Comment: I see what you mean and I fixed that part however I am still recieving the error